# Custom menu for all spreadsheets with Google editor add-on

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've built and published a Google Spreadsheet developer add-on, that I want to keep **private** (within my domain).
I want the add-on to create a custom menu item in all the spreadsheets I open (not only in the one hosting the script).
It works great in the original script using simple triggers

```js
function onInstall() {
    onOpen();
}

function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  var menu = ui.createAddonMenu();
  menu
    .addItem('Import Question', 'importQuestion')
    .addToUi();
}

function importQuestion() { etc..
```

To make it available in all spreadsheets, I turned it into an installable trigger (as indicated [in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable))

```js
function onInstall() {
    createSpreadsheetOpenTrigger();
}

function createSpreadsheetOpenTrigger() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('createMenu')
      .forSpreadsheet(ss)
      .onOpen()
      .create();
}

function createMenu() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  var menu = ui.createAddonMenu();
  menu
    .addItem('Import Question', 'importQuestion')
    .addToUi();
}

function importQuestion() { etc...
```

Unfortunately, the OnInstall() functions fails in this case, **even in the original script**.
But, if I run the same code manually in the original script, it works.
Also, if I get rid of the onInstall() function, the createSpreadsheetOpenTrigger() function is not called.
I understand it may be a matter of [authorizations](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/concepts/editor-auth-lifecycle), but I don't know how to overcome it
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwIQ4.png)

Comment: `Unfortunately, the OnInstall() functions fails in this case,` what do you mean, is there any error message?

Comment: maybe installable trigger works for you.